# Using SocketIO with Vuejs is not rendering the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, socket.io

So I'm trying to integrate SocketIO and I'm failing to because the only thing that's being rendered now is this, also I'm getting nothing in the console.

[image]

Instead this should be rendered
[image]

This is my server.js

```js
var app = require("express")();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.get("/chat", (req, res) => {
  res.send("/Users/admin/vue2/bulma/public/Chat.vue");
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("A user disconnected");
  });
});
http.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port *: 8081");
});
```

This is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico" />
    <!-- <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title> -->
    <title>Compare 2 Anime</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong
        >We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work
        properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
        continue.</strong
      >
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've failed to show the most important code ... the client code

Comment: You have to change this line `res.send("/Users/admin/vue2/bulma/public/Chat.vue")` you just return that string instead of serving the app.

Comment: Client code is just the ui so far and User 28 what should i replace that with then i can't use dirname because the directory is completely different